# Can I create a BUILD file that can reference and run several tests?

Tags: bazel, bazel-python

I have a python project with unit tests (unittest module) organized like this:

```
./WORKSPACE
./test/topic_a/BUILD
./test/topic_a/class_name_a_test.py
./test/topic_b/BUILD
./test/topic_b/class_name_b_test.py
```

The majority of the time this is fine and I run tests with:

```
bazel test //test/topic_a
```

I would like to have a BUILD at the project root to run all the tests in the project. I've been looking for a way to create a test where I can list all the labels from subdirectory BUILD files I want included, but have so far come up empty. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [test_suite](https://bazel.build/reference/be/general#test_suite) is what you're looking for. Something like this:

```py
test_suite(
    name = "the_tests",
    tests = [
        "//test/topic_a",
        "//test/topic_b",
    ],
)
```